# Use Docker rather than native/homebrew on Mac?

Tags: docker, environment

I currently have a LAMP stack installed on my mac running through Homebrew, which, to be honest hardly ever get's used.

Lately I have been working a lot with AngularJS and service based apps, so generally run the sites through a gulp / nodeJS based webserver.

I am totally frontend orientated, so very rarely do I play with backend related technologies other than the odd Drupal site and mysql.

I am interested to learn more NodeJS, perhaps even some Ruby, purely to understand programming more - not really for it to become my new job description.

So reading up on NodeJS a bit last night I read a lot about Docker, and installed it the toolkit and gui this morning. It looks pretty neat!

My question is: Would it work better for me to just run everything I need through Docker? For example, I can just install the mysql container, and turn it on when I need a db, and just spin up a drupal instance when I need one and connect it to my db instance?

I understand that running Docker on Mac is slower as it doesn't have the native Linux kernel and runs through a VM - but considering my needs from it, this should be okay?

I love the idea of just deploying containers, so will probably want to install Docker on my hosting environment too (VM in the cloud).

Follow up question: 90% of the sites I work on are AngularJS based frontends that speak to APIs that our backend guys build separately. Would it be overkill to have a Docker for each of those sites, or would I rather just run them all in one, or just bypass docker entirely for that (as I mentioned, I normally just load them up from within my Gulp's webserver)

Thanks a lot. I realise this is a n00b asking questions about big technology, but I'm trying to wrap my head around it and hopefully grow a bit in the process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The interest in deploying Docker container is **reproducibility**.
You can easily reproduce:

- either a complex development environment requiring the installation of numerous libraries (that you don't want to pollute directly your host)
- or an execution environment, for a given tool to run (like a web server)

If you are not likely to repeat a setup (for dev or exec), a docker container would bring little value.
But if you want to keep track of the exact specification of an environment (through its Dockerfile) *and* will deploy it not just on your workstation, but in other places as well, then docker is certainly a good option to consider.

Comment: Thanks for the information! I think I had an idea in my head that I thought Docker would cover, but doesn't.